# Set startup form for Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I made a C# store app in Visual studio 2013. All of the sudden the startup form is changed, so its no longer the Mainpage. I cannot find how to resolve this problem.
I found [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2whfskf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where I could do something in the properties of my project, but I was unable to resolve the problem.

Does anyone know how to change the startup form for a C# store app in Visual Studio 2013?

edit: here is the OnLaunched method as told in comments.

```
        protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {

#if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
#endif

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            await CatalogApp.Common.SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();
        }
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            CatalogApp.Common.SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "appFrame");
            // Set the default language
            rootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window+
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ShowItems), e.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }

            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably is a navigation statement like: `rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ItemsPage), e.Arguments);` in the

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
```

override in App.xaml.cs

If you are using this default, check `typeof(ItemsPage)` and the `e.Argument` statements.

Keep in mind, by default at activation,
 the application redirects to the last opened window.

**UPDATE**

```
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ShowItems), e.Arguments))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
}

rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
```

is a double navigation: first navigate to `ShowItems`, if succeeded navigate to `MainPage`. Why is that? I think this will lead to unexpected results.

Please try to remove

```
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ShowItems), e.Arguments))
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
}
```

and check the results.

By the way: Which one is the page you want to start with?

Comment: let me edit the page, so you can see that method. I have no clue where it goes wrong.

Comment: As you can see there is indeed a rootframe.navigate(typeof(MainPage), e arguments); Now what can i check about that other then that it should show the MainPage? (which it does not)

Comment: @Proliges: are you trying to test the `ShowItems` page? Then you should use another way? Does it work when you remove the test lines?

Comment: I want to start with MainPage. Now it starts with ShowItems. Note: this happend all of the sudden, went home, came back and no Mainpage startup :)

Comment: Oh when i remove that piece of code, it won't startup any more. Only the splashscreen, then it turns all black.

Comment: @Proliges: Maybe the `MainPage` is causing the problem. Is the markup valid? Is the page constructor raising an exception? You might want to check it with the same if statement.

Comment: @Proliges: either way, you might want to reconsider the double navigation ;)

Comment: It does so indeed, when i change ShowPage to Mainpage i will get an error in the debugger.